# error: Unable to find command: setup sass

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I have installed gulp, node-sass, gyp etc, however didn't work:
node -v : v9.10.0

> PS F:\ws\ionic\Listening> ionic setup sass [ERROR] Unable to find
>
> ### > command: setup sass

I changed the node version to v9.10.0 / v8.11.2 ,nothing helps .
I am almost crazy.....

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Just Chill!
It seems you are using NPM and ionic 3.
iF true, then yyou dont need the command.
Sass comes pre-installed.
Check your src/theme/variable

It is all the sass you may need.